# Bootstrap dropdown items hover on highlight is out of bounds

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I am using Bootstrap v4.3.1 with no modifications and I implemented a dropdown menu with the following markdown:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                   <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark nav-headlines" data-toggle="dropdown">A</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/B">B</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/C">C</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item nav-link text-dark nav-headlines" asp-area="" asp-page="/D">D</a>
                                        </div>
                                </li>
```

I did no changes to the Bootstrap code whatsoever.
The displayed hoveron on all dropdown items appear to be rendered partly out of bounds to the right.
The problem is that the dropdown-item class gets this rule `width: 100%;` which if I disable in Firefox/Chrome it seems to solve the issue.

I tried going the not recommended way and going to the bootstrap.css and commenting out the `width: 100%;` rule. It did not work.
The problem is that the browser somehow imports the rule not from bootstrap.css but rather _dropdown.scss even though such a file does not exist...

How do I fix my dropdown items hoveron?

I am using .NET 6 if that matters.

I also tried setting the CSS with inline CSS added to the DOM using jQuery but it also seems to have no effect (`$(".classnamehere").css("width","");`)...

Is this a bug from Bootstrap's side???

How does Bootstrap generate .scss files which I can see in the browser without actually having those files?? I don't import anything from the internet for Bootstrap, everything is local.

Here's a picture to visualize it:
[image: Bootstrap-dropdown-item-bug]

Comment: Do you have any other html tags outside `<li></li>` .If you put `<li></li>` outside other tags,will the css change?

Comment: Well the `<li></li>` is inside a `<div>` with these properties: `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" style="margin-top: 85px;">` and this div is in another div with the `container` class.

Comment: If you put `<li></li>`outside `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" style="margin-top: 85px;">`,will it change?

Comment: @YiyiYou I tried it out - it doesn't solve the issue or help in any way apparently

Comment: I add bootstrapv4.3.1 css with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`,and I do not see the browser imports the rule from _dropdown.scss.

Comment: @YiyiYou weird maybe it's ASP.NET Core's fault somehow?

Comment: I think it may be caused by the other css in _Layout.